# Overvoltage protection issues with analog signal

Tags: diodes, analog, switch-mode-power-supply, over-voltage-protection

I used this circuit to protect my analog input circuit from overvoltage. I put the models in a simulator and tested and it was showing that it works fine.

Coming now to real life, the circuit seems to work fine as an overvoltage protector but when I plug in the analog signal generator it seems it is affecting the analog signal 0..10 V. The generator is not showing a value more than 3 V although I'm putting it on 10 V which is weird.

The weirdest is with the board unpowered and the analog input generator or plug in it does the same I'm unable to see the 10 V.

Can you help me to know where exctely the problem and why my analog signal got affected?

[image]

Comment: Why would you plug-in (and where) a signal generator to your circuit?

Comment: I HAVE a connector that reads analog signals from 0 to 10V , lately my clients asked me to add an overvoltage protection to that circuit as sometime the user puts wrongly a power supply and the board got damaged ! so its mainly a connector to read analog signals

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how this relates to your question.

Comment: okey i will try to explain it more so mainly  i have a circuit that reads analog signal 0-10V , lately in the connector where the usr should put the analog signal , they mistakenly puts the power supply instead they plug in power supply in the connector where we should plug in our analog signal , i added an overvoltage circuit there so that board  do not get damaged when they do that mistakenly and supports that power , thus the overvoltage was there, but my analog signal got affected it cannot reach the 10V anymore

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please don't post text in SHOUTY CAPITALS. Simple and well-written text emphasises itself just fine without capitals, bold etc. Thanks. Also, please edit new information or improvements into your question, don't post them in comments as it's not a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Otherwise, readers have to piece together the full question from scattered fragments.

Comment: @Softcitysix what is the output impedance of your analogue signal? What is the output impedance of your signal generator?

Comment: The analog signal generator was used just in the testing phase to see whether my analog signal reading circuit is working fine

Comment: Are you not interested in answering the questions I asked?

Comment: My signal generator has 50ohms output impedance

Comment: A 50 ohm signal generator feeding your circuit will produce nearly twice the output voltage (even though the reading says otherwise). This is what signal generators do; they tell you what will be outputted to a load that is 50 ohm; your load is about 3 kohm. And, the peak value will be \$\sqrt2\$ higher if using a sinewave. All pretty much enough to trip your over-voltage protector. Use an oscilloscope to see the voltage produced. Added to that is the DC offset on the sig gen output.

Comment: Okey i wiil check it out , thanks